# Access and Refresh Tokens

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, monaca

I am using caspio rest api to authenticate my users in a mobile app.  Upon authenticating, I was given an access token to which I included in my AJAX call under the parameter 'Authorization' : Bearer [access token].

I understand that I can renew the token with the refresh token given to me where I can use the POST call.

My question is: prior to using the POST call for a new token, must I store the access token?

Also, the Caspio website advised this format for the POST call:

```
Method: POST
URL:    Token Endpoint
Body:   grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token= [token value]
Header parameters:
Authorization: Basic [string "Client_ID:Client_Secret" encoded in Base64]
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Should I also include the client ID and client secret in the parameters? Upon using Firefox's rest client, I'm getting a bad request (400) error.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I never using caspio rest api before. The answer base on my OAuth experiences.

> My question is: prior to using the POST call for a new token, must I store the access token?

YES! The OAuth 2.0 using the access token to switch the refresh token at first time.

> Should I also include the client ID and client secret in the parameters? Upon using Firefox's rest client, I'm getting a bad request (400) error.

According to the [api document](https://howto.caspio.com/integration/web-services-api/rest-api/authenticating-rest/). You should include the client ID and client secret in your request, like most OAuth 2.0 do.

The bad request (400) error you may see the [rfc6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2) to find further information.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  If you don't mind me asking how do I store the access token?

Can I simply make a variable access_token = [access token] and then have that included in my post call?

Comment: I think you didn't make a new variable, just put your got access_token in the parameter **refresh_token**.

Comment: Their website advised to put the refresh token value in the refresh token parameter.

Comment: If that, I cannot help you. :(  As my experiences mostly refresh token is always put access token in refresh_token parameter at first request (you don't have got refresh token before). Until you got a refresh token then you must put your refresh token in refresh_token parameter to renew token.

Comment: No worries!  I really appreciate the help! :)